# Is a try-catch-finally block mandatory to wrap data access code in an asp.net MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to asp.net mvc. I also have no enough background in web security. I am afraid what I did in my code contains hidden security issues.

Please see my code below first:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        GuestBookEntry gbe = new GuestBookEntry();
        return View(gbe);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(GuestBookEntry gbe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //any data access logic goes here.
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been successfully added.", gbe.Name);
            return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
        }
        else
            return View(gbe);
    }


    public ActionResult Confirmation()
    {
        string message = TempData["message"] as string;
        if (message != null)
        {
            return View((object)message);
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

### Question

1. Is it necessary to wrap the code in a controller with `try-catch-finally` block? In my understanding, it is not necessary because if exception occurs, asp.net framework will forward it to the default error page.
2. What is the best pattern to handle user request? In my code above, is it good enough?

Comment: Good enough in what regards?  This is pretty subjective.  I've seen code I'd never throw in production in production systems.  Standards vary from team to team and project to project, requirement to requirement.

Comment: @jfar: I have no idea in what regard my code above is good enough. I just got some code snippets from web articles and books. They have common patterns and now I combine all into my production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller class has an `OnException` virtual method that you can override.  This will allow you to handle exceptions in your controller if you want to do something special.  If you are fine with asp.net redirecting to an error page, then there is nothing wrong with doing that as well.

I'm not sure what data access has to do with your question, if you are concerned about releasing allocated resources in case of an exception (like an active connection to the database), then ideally whatever class has that resource implements `IDisposable` and therefore, you should be able to wrap it in a `using` statement block.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework wrapped using repository pattern. Releasing database connection is not my responsibility, isn't it?

Comment: You should dispose the database context if using Entity Framework, the context will be responsible for disposing its resources.